# Browser crashes on angularjs $http.get

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I'm working on a template system with angularJs, and I am including template files to my view with ng-include from an external js-file.

When I run my index.html the browser, it crashes after a long while. It seems as if the page continues to reload over and over, and my CPU monitor goes through the roof.

What on Earth can be wrong? I am fairly new at angularjs, so if anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd be very thankful.

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="angularTemplate" data-ng-controller="templateCtrl">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>{{ pageName + " - " + siteName }}</title>

 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <header data-ng-include="includeHeader()"></header>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/templateCtrl.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```js
var app = angular.module('angularTemplate', []);
app.controller('templateCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  
  $scope.includeHeader = function(){
    $http.get("./assets/php/mysql.php?action=getSiteSetup")
    .success(function(response){
      $scope.siteName = response.siteName;
      $scope.siteTagline = response.siteTagline;
    });
    return "./assets/templates/header.html";
  }
  
});
```

the mysql.php?action=getSiteSetup is a simple sql call which returns

```
{"siteName":"AngularJS Template","siteTagline":"Just another template...","siteBaseURL":"http:\/\/localhost\/angularjs_template\/"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For routing between pages you should use Angular-Route or ui.router.

It is described here with examples: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

This uses ng-view directive witch allows you to inject content based on called url from your web-app.
Here you have ng-view docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

I really recomend you to read it and solve it this way. This completly remodel your work but will let you work easier and faster in future. And also it will make much easier making a tests to it.

Also please past your header.html code for improving this answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this at once :)

Comment: Me and a lot of developers use it this way instead of dynamic including pages(what is standard thinking of php-devs wich is not best idea for angular, it brings more difficult sollutions when you expand your controllers etc in that included parts).

Comment: I did go about this with the way I'd do it in PHP in mind, so I see your point - being new to angularJs it's really nice to learn about the "better" ways to do something I'd be doing differently and just dig myself a deeper hole :)

Answer (score 2):

This issue exists because of the following two implementations:

```
<header data-ng-include="includeHeader()">
```

and

```
$scope.includeHeader = function(){
    $http.get("./assets/php/mysql.php?action=getSiteSetup")
    ...
}
```

You need to understand how AngularJS's scope works to detect change in scope. See [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Basically AngularJS will repeatedly rerun the expression given and compare it to its previous value to determine if its value has changed, if it did, then it will do whatever it needs upon scope variable change. Therefore `includeHeader()` here is rerun repeatedly every time AngularJS wants to check if things have changed. However inside your `includeHeader`, it triggers a network call every time. To make things into an infinite loop, one of the triggers for AngularJS to decide if it needs to check for scope change is upon the completion of `$http`. There's your infinite loop.

In short, do not use any expression for scope value check if it's process intensive and vice versa. `includeHeader` is NOT where you should put initialization code. Simply trigger it in controller.

Comment: Up'd for explaining what and where I did wrong, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Ajax request from inside the function that data-ng-include directive binds to in the controller so that the code looks like the following

```
var app = angular.module('angularTemplate', []);
app.controller('templateCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("./assets/php/mysql.php?action=getSiteSetup")
        .success(function(response){
          $scope.siteName = response.siteName;
          $scope.siteTagline = response.siteTagline;
      });
      $scope.includeHeader = function(){
        return "./assets/templates/header.html";
      }
    });
```

Note:

> You don't necessary need to bind the ng-include directive to a
>   function on the scope when the template is not loaded dynamically
>   based on user interactions